# Makefile error: missing close parenthesis

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am trying to download the Shakespeare to C compiler, and I have gotten to the point where I am trying to run the Makefile. I have tried `nmake -f Makefile`, but that returns fatal error U1000 on line 41:

[image: Command prompt error message]

I can't find anything wrong with the Makefile. There is the same number of "(" and ")".Line 41 says `MAKESCANNERINCLUDE = $(wildcard $(INCLUDEPATH)/*.{wordlist,metaflex})`.

Answer (score 0):

`$(wildcard …)` is a function call. Function calls are a [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) extension to the standard make syntax. Nmake expects a variable reference which would be just `$(something)`, so when it sees a space instead of a closing parenthesis, it reports a syntax error.

Use GNU make instead of Nmake.